# ExceptionInInitializerError thrown when creating a new TypefaceSpan object

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to change my ActionBar font in an android application.

Everything works just fine while running my code on a 4.3 device but when I'm trying to run it on a 2.3.3 device my app crashes.

This is the function that I'm using to change the font:

```
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("MyActivity");
    s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "myFont"), 0, s.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // Update the action bar title with the TypefaceSpan instance
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(s);
```

My app crashes thanks to the new TypefaceSpan line.

```
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at com.blabla.myapp.MainActivity.changeActionBarFont(MainActivity.java:41)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at com.blabla.myapp.MainActivity.setupGUIandListeners(MainActivity.java:27)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at com.blabla.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3768)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.util.LruCache
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     at com.blabla.myapp.TypefaceSpan.<clinit>(TypefaceSpan.java:34)
08-31 19:00:21.359: E/AndroidRuntime(3874):     ... 16 more
08-31 19:00:21.369: E/(186): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

I'm setting the font in my onCreate function.

Any help / ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be defining your own custom `TypefaceSpan` class (`com.blabla.myapp.TypefaceSpan`). In there, you are referring to `android.util.LruCache`. That class was added in API Level 12. Consider using `android.support.v4.util.LruCache` from the Android Support package, if you wish to support older devices.